# How to tag repeating Values in a table / column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I have a table which is a join of 3 tables that shows below information.

```
|| OrderID || Order Date || Customer || Customer City || Product || Amount ||
```

I want to get another column as `|| Dual Purchase ||`  if a customer has ordered a product more then once on the same date?

The value should be `YES` or `NO`

So if John buys coke on 16th June in 2 separate order then it should have `YES` against both order IDs

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you..

```
Select
            O.OrderID,O.[Order Date],c.Customer,c.[Customer City],P.Product,O.Amount,a.[More then Once]
from        Orders O
inner join  Customers C
on          O.Customer_Id=C.Customer_Id
inner join  Product P
On          O.Product_Id=P.Product_Id
Cross Apply (   select Case when count(1)>1 then 'Yes' Else 'No' [More then Once] end from Orders
                where Customer_Id=O.Customer_Id and cast([Order Date] as date)=cast(O.[Order Date] as date)
                group by Customer_Id,cast([Order Date] as date)
            ) a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT OrderID 
    , OrderDate
    , Customer 
    , CustomerCity
    , Product 
    , Amount 
    , Case when Count(Product) Over(Partition by OrderDate, Customer, Product) > 1 
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end as DualPurchase
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window funcion [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to define double records by `OrderID` and `Customer`. Check, if the row is greater than 1:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (OrderID int, Customer  int, OrderDate date)

INSERT INTO @Table 
VALUES
(1,2, Getdate()),
(1,2, DATEADD(day,1,Getdate())),
(1,2, DATEADD(day,1,Getdate())),
(2,3, Getdate()),
(2,3, DATEADD(day,1,Getdate()))

SELECT 
    *,
    IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.OrderID, t.Customer ORDER BY t.OrderID) > 1, 'YES', 'NO') AS DualPurchase
FROM @Table AS t
```